# Showing the number of items in WooCommerce mini cart

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am creating a cart link for my mobile header. I just want to show number of cart items after the cart icon. No text, only a number.

How can I do it?

My code is something like this:

```
 <div class="mobile-cart">
 <a href="mywebsite.com/cart">
 <img src="cart.png">
 Here should be the code for no. of items
 </a>
 </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the method **`get_cart_contents_count()`** from **`WC_cart`** class, this way:

```
<div class="mobile-cart">
    <a href="mywebsite.com/cart">
         <img src="cart.png">
         <span><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count( ); ?></span>
     </a>
</div>
```

Reference: [WC_Cart class - get_cart_contents_count() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_cart_contents_count)

Comment: Thanks man. You are awesome. You solved a big problem of mine